# Search records only in options select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have multi-level optgroup in my select2 box.

I would like to search items only in `<option></option>` tags.

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Customizing how results are matched](https://select2.org/searching#customizing-how-results-are-matched).